# File Manager that can restore tabs Ubuntu

Tags: file-management, ubuntu

Can you suggest some popular file managers for ubuntu 18.04 which can restore opened tabs after closing and opening the application. It should retain the tabs across restart as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DoubleCommander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)

It is double pane and multiple tabs in each pane. The tabs are restored at startup.

Double Commander is a free cross platform open source file manager with two panels side by side. It is inspired by Total Commander and features some new ideas.

some key featuresInternal text editor (F4)  with syntax hightlightingBuilt in file viewer (F3) to view files of in hex, binary or text formatArchives are handled like subdirectories. You can easily copy files to and from archives. Supported archive types: ZIP, TAR, GZ, BZ2, XZ, LZMA, 7Z and also RPM, CPIO, DEB, RAR, ZIPXExtended  search function with full text search in any filesConfigurable button bar to start external programs or internal menu commandsTotal Commander WCX, WDX, WFX and WLX plug-ins support

Unicode supportMost operations working in backgroundMulti-rename toolTabbed interfaceCustom columnsFile operations logging